# Need clarification on private and public keys and certificates

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I have checked a lot of tutorials and examples on using openssl but none are clear enough or complete.

I understand the Diffie-Hellman algorithm itself but I am not clear on how openssl works.

How can you generate the public key from the private key without connection to the server?

Both client and server must use the same prime and base so unless they are predetermined  (are they?) you cannot generate the public key from the private key until you have agreed upon prime and base.

Where is the prime and base, in the certificate?

Should the client and server have a copy of the SAME certificate? The client just retrieves the server certificate and sees it is the same as its own?

Is the validation of the certificate done automatically in the handshake or it has to be programmed?

And when you encrypt and decrypt, is that not done automatically by the openssl stack, do I have to call encrypt and decrypt functions to do that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because its not about programming or development. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3):

During [SSL/TLS handshake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Basic_TLS_handshake), server and client needs first to negotiate common *cipher suite*, supported to both parties. If they agree on DHE key exchange and RSA authentication (a very common scenario), server always sends *Certificate* ([RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), section 7.4.2) and *ServerKeyExchange* (7.4.3) messages to client, then client sends *ClientKeyExchange* (7.4.7) message in response.

> How can you generate the public key from the private key without
> connection to the server?
>
> Both client and server must use the same prime and base so unless they
> are predetermined (are they?) you cannot generate the public key from
> the private key until you have agreed upon prime and base.
>
> Where is the prime and base, in the certificate?

Now a bit of math about Diffie-Hellman flow applied in SSL/TLS protocol:

Server chooses prime (*p*) and base (generator *g* of group *Zp*). Usually it is fixed in server source code, or sysadmin can provide their own dhparam file (for example generated by `openssl dhparam` command). It can be public and reused. Only the length of *p* is important to security.

Server generates randomly its secret value (*Xs*) and public value (*Ys = g^Xs mod p*). It sends *ServerKeyExchange* message with *p*, *g*, *Ys* to client.

Client receives *p*, *g*, *Ys*. It generates randomly its secret value (*Xc*) and public value (*Yc = g^Xc mod p*). It sends back *ClientKeyExchange* message with *Yc* in response.

Both parties now can compute common master secret (*S = Yc^Xs = (g^Xc)^Xs = g^(XcXs) mod p*, *S = Ys^Xc = (g^Xs)^Xc = g^(XsXc) mod p*). It is used in further computations.

> Should the client and server have a copy of the SAME certificate? The
> client just retrieves the server certificate and sees it is the same
> as its own?

Client receives *Certificate* message containing server's cert (with intermediate trust chain). Client validates it by checking if it can reconstruct a trust path from your cert, via intermediate CA certs, to a root (self-signed) CA cert installed in his system by default.

> Is the validation of the certificate done automatically in the
> handshake or it has to be programmed?
>
> And when you encrypt and decrypt, is that not done automatically by the openssl stack, do I have to call encrypt and decrypt functions to do that?

SSL/TLS protocol is designed to be totally transparent to any app using it. Its implementations (such as OpenSSL) contain all necessary functions to validate a cert (authentication), to establish common secret (key exchange) or to encrypt/decrypt data (symmetric cipher). You don't need to write those cryptographic algorithms yourself.

Comment: Nicely clear but a few nitpicks: the client *can* also use a cert (with privatekey) *if* the server requests (but this is fairly rare); SSL/TLS *can* also do "anonymous" DH where neither side uses a cert, but this of course allows impersonation and is usable is only in special cases. As a client, with server auth/cert as is usual, current OpenSSL checks the cert is valid for *somebody* (chaining, signatures, KU, BC and optionally revocation) but not that it is for the *correct* server (hostname match); enhancements for this are now in development. ...

Comment: ... And last, "totally" transparent is an exaggeration. The stack certainly handles all the details of handshake and encryption and MAC (which was the question asked), and the API may look almost the same (e.g. Java `SSLSocket extends Socket`), but there are minor differences that sometimes matter, particularly as to fragmentation and closedown. OpenSSL `SSL_read` and `SSL_write` are *mostly* like TCP `recv` and `send`, but not entirely.

Comment: I agree :) Feel free to update my answer.